# How to edit a file loaded with Deno?

Tags: file, stdout, deno

Recently I started to play around with Deno and I was reading and coding follow the instructions on Deno manual.

After a while, I tried to edit the content copied by the file but I cannot find how.

Can someone help me?

```js
for (let i = 0; i < Deno.args.length ; i++) {
  let filename = Deno.args[i];
  let file = await Deno.open(filename);
  await Deno.copy(file, Deno.stdout);
  file.close()
}
```

Those were the terminal commands used by me.

`deno run --allow-read hello.ts password.txt users.txt`

And the output:

```
Compile file:///home/lustepe/Dev/Practices/deno-test/hello.ts
<password>
<user>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I tried to reproduce the issue and it works fine. Maybe I could be misunderstanding your question. Mind elaborating on "I tried to edit the content copied by the file but I cannot find how."

Comment: Your code works fine, just make sure that you already have the files `password.txt` and `users.txt`

Comment: Lucas, did you post someones username/password on the internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now Deno supports editing JSON files using [Deno.writeFile](https://doc.deno.land/https/github.com/denoland/deno/releases/latest/download/lib.deno.d.ts#Deno.writeFile):

```js
const encoder = new TextEncoder();
const data = encoder.encode("Hello world\n");
await Deno.writeFile("hello1.txt", data);  // overwrite "hello1.txt" or create it
await Deno.writeFile("hello2.txt", data, {create: false});  // only works if "hello2.txt" exists
await Deno.writeFile("hello3.txt", data, {mode: 0o777});  // set permissions on new file
await Deno.writeFile("hello4.txt", data, {append: true});  // add data to the end of the file
```

I couldn't find a way to edit files with high flexibility, such as by position, replacement or regex.

Then your only alternative becomes loading the file into memory, editing it and then writing the whole file.

```js
// load file
const decoder = new TextDecoder("utf-8");
const content = decoder.decode(await Deno.readFile('data.json'));
const json = JSON.parse(content);

// sets new data
json.data = "new data";

// write new data
const newtxt = JSON.stringify(json);
const newdata = new TextEncoder().encode(newtxt)
await Deno.writeFile("data.json", newdata);

let data = await Deno.readFile("data.json");
console.log(decoder.decode(data));
```